# How do I make the turtles wait for the countdown?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I want my turtles to go after the countdown finishes, but I cant figure out a way to do it. There are other issues, but i want to fix this first. I've tried time.sleep, and other stuff. I'm fairly new, so i'm not sure what do to. this is for a class as well, and I'm not finding good answers.
here is the code

```
    from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import choice
import time

FONT = ('Arial', 36, 'bold')

def race():
    while turtle_1.xcor() < 200 or 200 > turtle_2.xcor():
        choice([turtle_1, turtle_2]).forward(10)

def countdown(seconds=3):
  if countdown() < 3:
    turtle_1.pendown()
    turtle_2.pendown()
    turtle_1.forward(400)
    turtle_2.forward(400)
  
    if seconds < 1:
        screen.ontimer(race)
    else:
        pen.write(seconds, align='center', font=FONT)
        screen.ontimer(lambda: countdown(seconds - 1), 1000)
      

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('green')

marker = Turtle()
marker.hideturtle()
marker.speed('fastest')
marker.color('white')
marker.width(5)

marker.penup()
marker.goto(200, 300)
marker.pendown()

marker.right(90)
marker.forward(600)

pen = Turtle()
pen.hideturtle()

turtle_1 = Turtle()
turtle_1.shape('turtle')
turtle_1.color('red')
turtle_1.penup()
turtle_1.goto(-400, 200)


turtle_2 = turtle_1.clone()
turtle_1.color('blue')
turtle_2.goto(-400, -200)

countdown()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put the `countdown()` function back to the way I wrote it, you should be fine.  There's no reason the turtles should move `forward(400)` every second of the count down:

```
def countdown(seconds=3):
    pen.clear()
  
    if seconds < 1:
        screen.ontimer(race)
    else:
        pen.write(seconds, align='center', font=FONT)
        screen.ontimer(lambda: countdown(seconds - 1), 1000)
```